# write multiple lines to a file in one line command

Tags: command-line, cat

I have a file that i want to create using command line, using the cat tool (or something similar).
The text in question is multi line and is in a certain format (yaml) - which i want to maintain.

Is there a way to write a file using one line command?

Comment: But you are not willing to show us the text (or some similar in the right format)?

Comment: Errrr...`vim` ? ;)

Answer (score 28):

```
$ cat > test.yaml << EOF
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
EOF

$ cat test.yaml
```

The `>` symbol refers to create a `test.yaml` file

Comment: there is a slight difference EOF VS EOT depends on the requirement you can prefer it but both are terminating the file stream.

Comment: If your not comfortable with cat command, you can go with echo command.

Comment: The here-document delimiter, `EOF`, may be _any_ piece of string. `EOT` or `MY_DOCUMENT` would work in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Ram You are wrong (in this context); you obviously misunderstand what is happening there.

Answer (score 5):

```
cat <<\EOT >target_file
foo
    bar
        baz
EOT
```

Comment: the backslash before the EOT isn't necessary.  It does nothing - an escaped E is still an E.

Comment: @cas: Quoting one or more characters in the here document delimiter word affects the interpretation of the here document. It does nothing *for the above example data,* because it doesn’t contain any dollar signs or other special characters.

Comment: ah, okay. i thought the entire word had to be quoted.  the bash and ksh man pages make it clear that it happens if any part of the word is quoted. man page for dash/ash just say "if the delimiter is quoted" (implying the whole delimiter, but quoting any part works, as in bash/ksh).

Comment: How do you combine this with sudo when target file requires root permissions?

Comment: @mjs The easiest was is probably to make it a `bash` argument: `sudo bash -c "cat <<\EOT >target_file <newline>foo <newline>    bar <newline>        baz <newline>EOT"`. Pay attention to quotes in the EOT block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wouldn't copy the file. But if you want `cat` and don't want to copy, then you will be typing anyhow. So instead of using the typical `<<` here-document redirection, you can do simply this:

```
cat > target_file
```

Now you're typing to `cat` and `cat` writes to `target_file`. Once you finish typing, hit once more <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then on empty line hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to end. What you've typed should be in the `target_file`. Check it with:

```
cat target_file
```